# ios:tableview and webview scroll separately in scrollview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UItableview at the top and a webView beside it together inside a scrollView. What I wanna do is as theie total length stretch beyond the height of screen, I'd like them to stick together to scroll. But the situation now is they scroll separately.

UPDATE:
I found the problem may be I the scrollView content size not working. Is it not working when autolayout is enabled? How do I set scrollview content size in the case of autolayout?

below the image is in a webview below the tableview.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell with web view in cell view, Then return Custom Cell in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Also note that, do not load web data to cell OR perform animation during cell(with web-view) is loaded to memory/queued  on main thread.[image]